# xdotool does not terminate

Tags: command-line, window-manager, xdotool

`xdotool click 1` works as it should: the left mouse button is clicked once.

On the other hand, whenever I enter `xdotool behave_screen_edge bottom click 1` in the terminal, the command does not terminate. It's like the terminal is still waiting for input from me:

[image]

same goes for example of a command from the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/xdotool.1.html) (!), `xdotool behave_screen_edge bottom-left search --class google-chrome windowactivate`

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

Obviously, those commands run an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), and do what they should do *until you terminate the command* (or close the terminal):

```
xdotool behave_screen_edge bottom click 1
```

clicks the left button if you hit the bottom of your screen, and

```
xdotool behave_screen_edge bottom-left search --class google-chrome windowactivate
```

activates `Chrome` windows when you move the mouse to bottom-left. Both commands ***do that on every occasion, until you kill the process:***

[image]

#### How to run it on startup

From a comment, I understand you want to run commands like this on startup. To add it to Startup Applications:

- on XFCE (Xubuntu):

  Settings > Session and Startup > Application Autostart > Add. Add the command:

  ```
    /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && xdotool behave_screen_edge bottom-left search --class google-chrome windowactivate"
  ```
- On Unity:

  Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the (same) command:

  ```
    /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && xdotool behave_screen_edge bottom-left search --class google-chrome windowactivate"
  ```

Comment: @DKBose obviously, they run in a loop, waiting for an event to happen (the mouse to hit the bottom/bottom-left), exactly like a `mainloop()` of a gui.

Comment: @DKBose see updated answer

Comment: oh well! I should have seen that. So if  I wanted  to keep this behaviour up forever,  I'd need to run it in a seperate terminal forever?

Comment: I was thinking of a way to fix the `xfce`  issue that if you drag a window to the  top of your screen, it doesn't maximize but only takes half of the space, by xdotool

Comment: @Blauhirn see my updated answer :)

Comment: @Blauhirn re- reading your comment, there might be a more elegant way to achieve that (if this one works at all?): just double click on the top of the window?

Comment: well yes haha, that'd of course also work :D thanks for your help